# How can I download all images available in a URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, mechanize

I want to download all images of a product available in this link:

```
http://www.veromoda.in/vero-moda-women-s-white-coloured-casual-shirt-4.html
```

I know how to download a single image by passing the URL of each image:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
link = 'http://www.veromoda.in/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/1/0/10074424-snowwhite-1.jpg'
agent.get(link).save "images/pic.jpg"
```

How can I download all images of that product by passing a single url?

Comment: You will need to use some kind of html parser to extract the `src` attribute from all `img` tags.  Nokogiri is a popular choice.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is much too broad. We don't know your expertise level, so we'd have to write a tutorial starting with the little you showed us in your question. Instead, you need to do more research further and try to solve this, then, when you have a specific problem, ask about it. Your question has multiple answers both on SO and elsewhere on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

This is the core to finding all images in a page:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'restclient'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(RestClient.get('http://www.iana.org/domains/reserved'))
images = doc.search('img').map{ |img| img['src'] }
images[0..2] # => ["/_img/2013.1/iana-logo-header.svg", "/_img/2013.1/icann-logo.svg"]
```

Loop over the `src` URLs in `images`, `get` each, then save it.

You can see there's going to need to be some fix-up of the URLs to make them fully defined, so that's part of the task of downloading the files. You need to figure out how to do that.

You'll also need to figure out how to tell what is an image you want, versus one that is advertising or navigation elements, positioning, etc.

You'll also want to figure out how to be a good network citizen and honor the robots.txt file if the target site has one, plus throttle your requests to not saturate their network and bog down their server(s) if you are on an image sack-and-pillage run, otherwise expect to be banned.

Answer (score 1):

I am done this by following way. I am posting here it may be useful to any one.

```
url="http://www.veromoda.in/elastic/search/fetch/?q=#{id}"
agent.get("#{url}")
links=agent.page.css('a').map { |k| k.attributes['href'].value }
if links.empty?
  puts "Images for #{id} not available"
else
  links.each do |l|
    agent.get("#{l}")
    agent.page.image_urls
    image_links=agent.page.search('.lSPager').css('img')

    image_links.each do |link|
      image_name=File.basename(link.attributes["src"])
      agent.get(link.attributes["src"]).save "vero_moda_images/#{id}/#{image_name}"
    end
 end
 puts "Your #{id} Images Downloaded"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri) gem for parsing the HTML. Use [selectorgadget](http://selectorgadget.com/)
to understand the tags, structure and pattern in the HTML to parse and store required data.

Comment: Mechanize can do it, but very often it's much faster and easier to use Nokogiri. Mechanize uses Nokogiri for its parsing of the document, which is a testament to Nokogiri's power.

Comment: Be very careful using any browser-based tool to identify the selector/path to an element in a page. Browsers "fix-up" HTML, changing it from their original form prior to displaying it, and reflect that changed HTML in their source view. Instead, using `curl` or `wget` or OpenURI to retrieve the page and look at it in a text editor.